# How to change color of the DataPoint in LineGraphSeries with highest/lowest Y value?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-graphview

I have array of `DataPoints` with **x, y coords**. I want to highlight `DataPoint` with **highest/lowest** **Y** value on `GraphView`.

I can extract highest/lowest Y value by:

`lineGraphSeries.getHighestValueY` or `lineGraphSeries.getLowestValueY`. But what I need is to get actual DataPoint from the series with highest/lowest value and change its color.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Comment: It seems that it's not posible to change the color of a single datapoint in GraphView at the moment.

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of is to use a BarGraphSeries an its setValueDependentColor method. It allows you to define some rules for coloring ..

Comment: @martin1337 did you find any solution?